# Java JIT gotchas

Tags: java, jit

If I want to compare the speed of 2 implementations of an algorithm, is there any gotcha about the JIT I should be aware of? For example, how many iterations does it take the JIT to "warm-up" (if it does - I am not very familiar with the JIT)? I have a merge-like algorithm in mind, where I want to compare using an iterator and using raw primitive arrays directly. I want to understand how well the JIT can handle the iterator-based algorithm.

My fear is that my comparison wouldn't be relevant because I didn't let the benchmark run long enough, and the JIT didn't really have a chance to do its job.

Also, what would be the best reference to understand the JIT in depth (besides reading source code).

- One more question: is -server the best option to use to tell the JIT to work hard?

Comment: As with all thorough benchmarks, one or more "dry runs" are typically performed before taking any statistics. This does things like fill instruction caches, perform JIT compilation, conditionally initialize any static data, etc.

Comment: OK - I'm planning on running the merge-like algorithm on 2 sparse vectors many times - I'm guessing the first few iterations will allow the JIT to understand what to do. But how many iterations is enough for that? Should I run that loop at least 1,000 times? More? Less? How fast does the JIT latches on to the relevant optimizations?

Comment: Use pre-built benchmarking libraries if you can; don't try to understand the JIT yourself.  (I use [Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/).)

Comment: The question as currently written strikes me as broad and vague. It might help if you ran your benchmarks, posted your results, and asked for feedback about anything specific you are suspicious of.

Comment: Aaron - Yes, the purpose is to understand how to benchmark in Java, not to look at a specific example. Although I can also post a specific example for review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any gotcha about the JIT I should be aware of?

too many to mention. ;)

Don't forget the CPU and cache does its own optimisation and performance improvements.

> , how many iterations does it take the JIT to "warm-up" (if it does - I am not very familiar with the JIT)?

At least 10,000.  I would perform the test for 2-10 seconds, a number of times.

> what would be the best reference to understand the JIT in depth

I don't think there is one "best" reference. Its a very complex subject.